# Geoportal resource URL to Geoserver does not show Preview link in search result

Tags: wms, esri-geoportal-server

I have a Geoportal catalog entry with a resource URL like:

> http://data.ilri.org:8080/geoserver/nurc/Arc_Sample/wms?request=getcapabilities

However the preview link is not shown in the search result.

I thought that maybe this was related to the ***resourceLinkBuilder.preview.filter*** variable in gpt.xml but even if I set the filter to empty (No filters at all)

```
<parameter key="resourceLinkBuilder.preview.filter" value=""/>
```

The preview link still does not show.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Please note that if I call the Geoportal Preview Window with my URL the Preview works fine.

> http://data.ilri.org/geoportal/catalog/livedata/preview.page?url=http://data.ilri.org:8080/geoserver/nurc/Arc_Sample/wms?request=getcapabilities

Many thanks,

Carlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make sure you register the complete GetCapabilities URL:
http://data.ilri.org:8080/geoserver/nurc/Arc_Sample/wms?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.3.0

with this URL I am able to register the service in Geoportal Server 1.2.4 and do see the preview link as expected.

Marten